# How can I extend OData from Server?

Tags: sapui5

I receive OData from our Gateway. I.e. There is a status code in the model. In my sap.m.Table I want to display instead of the code a short label which is not stored on my server. How can I do that? The texts are stored in a ResourceModel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in the Developer Guide for [Formatter functions](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de.html).
With them you could do something like this:

In your View add the formatter to the binding of your status Text.

```xml
<Text text="{path: 'status', formatter: '.formatStatus'}" />
```

In the Controller add a method to format the input.

```js
Controller.prototype.formatStatus = function (sStatus) {
    return this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText(sStatus);
};
```